# Jasig CAS: page reloads on 5th attempt to login

Tags: ldap, cas, jasig

There is CAS+LDAP authorization system.

My login page reloads on 5th wrong attempt to login. For example, if I try to login with wrong password from 1 to 4 times, only *password* field cleared. On 5th attempt page reloads (even if password is right) and both *username* and *password* fields cleared.

And there is no log output neither in CAS nor in LDAP at this moment.

I have spent two weeks in search for solution, but nothing found.

Thank for advance.

P.S. Sorry for my english :)

---------- EDIT ----------

After **Ioannis Baourdos**' answer:

1. The hidden field `name="execution"` with `value="${flowExecutionKey}"` presents in my custom **casLoginView.jsp**
2. I have also checked my log on 5th attempt. Here I see the same output if I reload page manually.
3. In my web-browser I repeatedly checked `name="execution"` value. Here the values:

Action -> Value

1) opened page -> e1s1

2) 1st wrong attempt -> e1s2

3) 2nd wrong attempt -> e1s3

4) 3rd wrong attempt -> e1s4

5) 4th wrong attempt -> e1s5

6) Next either right or wrong attempt (page reloads after submit) -> e7s1

Logically somewhere there is some parameter with value "5". I have not found it yet...

Question is still open ;)

**---------- SOLVED ----------**

There was link to not existing .png file in my custom css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### More on Suggestion (2)

I was searching for a 5 parameter all over the place myself.
I then reverted back to using the default UI/theme from jasig and the redirection was not happening. So in my case I was 100% certain that there was something wrong with my code.

I left it as it was, went on production and then I had a new CAS integration case which again was implemented with a different custom form.

The 5 became 2 ... same version etc etc. So I jumped into tamper data on firefox to see exactly what was happening.

In the first case it was a custom CSS I was using, that was trying to load another CSS that did not exist.

In the second case, I had upgraded JQuery to 1.10 and I placed the script tag at /includes/top.jsp. I also did not include the /jsp/cas.js file.

With firebug I noticed that this JS file was asking for 
@sourceMappingURL=jquery-1.10.2.min.map

which was missing from my JS folder.

to cut a long story short, when I moved my JS inclusions at the bottom.jsp in the same order as CAS default UI and after I removed / fixed all the related imports/includes from my custom JS/CSS files, the issue stopped.

-- old --
if you are designing you custom login form there may be a view cases that cause the redirect.

### new suggestion (1)

there are a few cases when this is happening. 
If you enable logging you may notice this popping up after the 5fth time:
***'initialFlowSetupAction'***

in this case most frequent issue is that you are using a custom form and you forgot to set up the 'flow' hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey" value="${flowExecutionKey}" />
```

or on 3.5.2

```
<input type="hidden" name="execution" value="${flowExecutionKey}" />
```

### new suggestion (2)

I also run into a weird case lately ... I was using a custom CSS which 
was properly loaded BUT it contained imports to files that were missing:
*@import url(ui.datepicker.css);*

this was also evident via TamperData (2 calls to cas/login) and also via firebug, 302 redirect to cas/login from request for ui.datepicker.css

ps. this is my first post :)

Comment: thanks for answer!
1. I have checked: it is not Throttling

2. <input type="hidden" name="execution" value="${flowExecutionKey}" /> exist in my login page

3. I am quitelly misunderstood about **new suggestion (2)**

Comment: hey, Ioannis! I solved this issue thank to your **Suggestion(2)**. There was link to not existed .png file in my custom css. First post - and so useful ))